# Graphing criterion benchmarks taking different orders of magnitude of time

Tags: haskell, haskell-criterion

I have a Criterion benchmark where each `bgroup` corresponds to a test, and within each `bgroup` there are two `bench` values of the test with different options. For example:

```
main = defaultMain
    [bgroup "test1" [bench "v1" test1_1, bench "v2" test1_2]
    ,bgroup "test2" [bench "v1" test2_1, bench "v2" test2_2
    -- lots more tests
    ]
```

Within each `bgroup` the two `bench` tests are comparable. However, `test1` takes 2000 micro seconds, while `test2` takes 45 micro seconds. The overview graph (which is most useful for what I want to do) displays different tests on the same axes, so I can clearly see the differences in `test1`, but `test2` is hard to see.

Is it possible to normalise each `bgroup` for plotting? Or show them on separate axes? Or should I dump the CSV data and plot what I want myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is definitely amongst the shortcomings of Criterion. I've been bitten by the same problem multiple times.

The standard approach I take to work around this is just to generate an individual executable per each comparison unit. A special `benchmark` target has been added in the latest versions of Cabal, so I declare a benchmark target per each comparison unit in the `.cabal` file. Then I can run each comparison using `cabal bench [target-name]`. Yeah, it is all far from comforting, but it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

I have just released a library [**criterion-plus**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-plus-0.1.0). It is a dome library over "criterion", which approaches the issue you're experiencing amongst others. It allows you to declare multiple "standoffs", which generate independent "criterion" report files. Another important issue it fixes is the ability to exclude "setup/teardown" phases from benchmarking, which "criterion" does not let you do.

Here is an example of how this library is supposed to be used:

```
import CriterionPlus
import qualified SomeMySQLLib as MySQL
import qualified SomePostgreSQLLib as PostgreSQL

main = 
  benchmark $ do
    standoff "Inserting rows" $ do
      subject "MySQL" $ do
        -- Exclude the "setup" phase from measurement:
        pause
        connection <- liftIO $ MySQL.openConnection
        -- Measure what we want:
        continue
        liftIO $ MySQL.insertAThousandRows connection
        -- Exclude the "teardown" phase from measurement:
        pause
        liftIO $ MySQL.closeConnection connection
      subject "PostgreSQL" $ do
        -- This is how we can exclude the "setup" phase from monad transformers:
        pause
        PostgreSQL.runSession $ do
          lift $ continue
          PostgreSQL.insertAThousandRows
          -- Exclude "teardown":
          lift $ pause
    -- Each standoff generates an independent report file:
    standoff "Querying" $ do
      subject "MySQL" $ error "So on..."
      subject "PostgreSQL" $ error "So on..."
```